# "WindowsCryptographicException: The system cannot find the path specified" when trying to use DPAPI from LocalSystem account

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, .net-6.0, dpapi

I use `DPAPI` with `DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine` in a Windows Service.
I tested my service by running it directly on my user account. It works.
Also works when run as administrator.

Then I install it as a Windows Service on `LocalSystem` account.
Then it throws something like this:

```
Exception Info: Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The system cannot find the path specified.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.ProtectOrUnprotect(Byte[] inputData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope, Boolean protect)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Byte[] encryptedData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
```

I changed service user to my user account and it works. So - the data protection fails only if the service is run as `LocalSystem`.

Fragment that throws:

```cs
public byte[] Unprotect(byte[] data, DataProtectionScope scope = DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
    => ProtectedData.Unprotect(data, null, scope.AsSystemType());
```

The `scope` is set to `DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine`.

I also tried to run the service as "NT Authority\NetworkService" user. Same behavior. Can't access local machine protection keys.

Why is that and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems like a bug in Windows DPAPI to me. It requires a user account different from `LOCAL SYSTEM` and `NETWORK SERVICE`.

As `LOCAL SYSTEM` is in `Administrator` role, I see no reason why the key access is denied for the user.

As a workaround I just use a different API.

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection` - to be exact.

That API requires the new key to be created for the first time.

For practical implementation see:
https://github.com/HTD/Woof/tree/master/Packages/Woof.DataProtection
https://github.com/HTD/Woof/blob/master/Packages/Woof.DataProtection/Api/WindowsLocalSystemKey.cs

You can also check the https://github.com/HTD/Woof/tree/master/Demos/Woof.ServiceInstaller.TestService
for testing of a data protected service configuration.